# PHP code for converting the value of star rating

Tags: php

I have given rating values form 1.0 to 6.0. Here 1.0 is the best and 6.0 is the baddest rating. I have to convert the ratings like this.
If 1.0 is the given rating value i will have to show 5.0
and IF 6.0 is the given rating value i will have to show 1.0
So if 3.0 is the given rating value i will have to show 2.5 and so on.I am grabbing this 1 to 6 ratings from an external website. Need to convert it to 1 to 5 to my website.

Comment: Why if they can rate it 1 to 6 are you showing it as 1 to 5?

Comment: I am grabbing this 1 to 6 ratings from an external website. My client wants to convert this to 1 to 5 to his site.

Comment: SO is not a „write code for me“ Community. Write the code by your own and come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Why would 1 become 5 and 6 become 1, yet 3 becomes 2.5?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay sir thank u...Next time this will not happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more about math than it is about php.

So let's see, first we need to reverse the values. Because we want change on which end of the rating is worst and best respectively.

```
$reverseRating = 7.0 - $inputRating;
```

This transforms `1.0` into `6.0` and `6.0` into `1.0` etc.

Now all left to do is scale the values down from 6 stars (input range: 6 - 1 = `5.0`) into 5 stars (output range: 5 - 1 = `4.0`). For that we will shift everything down to 0, shrink it, then shift it back to 1.

```
$outputRating = ($reverseRating - 1.0) / 5.0 * 4.0 + 1.0;
```

Written as compact one-liner this results in

```
$outputRating = (6.0 - $inputRating) * 0.8 + 1.0;
```

**Note**

Your conclusion that the input `3.0` should result in `2.5` is wrong.

Because the lowest value is 1, not 0, the center value on the input rating scale is *not* 3, it is **3.5**:

6 5 4 **(3.5)** 3 2 1

Same goes for the output center value, it's *not* 2.5, it is **3**:

1 2 **3** 4 5

`3.0` on input is actually *slightly better* than center and will map to `3.4` on output.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank u so much....:)